# cors issue with fetch api

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, fetch-api, isomorphic-fetch-api

I am calling an API with `isomorphic-fetch` with Fetch API. I was getting CORS issue as API was on different domain (this works in production).

To develop locally, I ran chrome browser in non-secure mode and added  `{ credentials: "include" }` as part of request headers so that cookies will be sent along with request.

my dev domain is `localhost.abc.com:8080` and api is on `myapi.abc.com`, although i am getting 200 OK response, i am unable to read the response because of below error:

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
>   must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'

This is where I have started missing jQuery AJAX call in relation to the Fetch API.

Comment: Could you reduce your test case by eliminating the `isomorphic-fetch` and update your question? This can probably be reproduced using `window.fetch` in the dev console. Also, please provide an example of how you would accomplish your goal with `jQuery.ajax`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to specific domain you want to whitelist, eg. `localhost.abc.com:8080` in your case.